# Bazel, I want to avoid all the "convenience symlinks" to be generated

Tags: build, bazel

When you build a Bazel project, your WORKSPACE project root directory is populated by a bunch of convenience symlinks:

```
<workspace-name>/                         <== The workspace directory
  bazel-my-project => <...my-project>     <== Symlink to execRoot
  bazel-out => <...bin>                   <== Convenience symlink to outputPath
  bazel-bin => <...bin>                   <== Convenience symlink to ...
  bazel-genfiles => <...genfiles>         <== Convenience symlink to ...
```

See the official doc, [Bazel internals: Directory layout](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/output_directories.html#bazel-internals-directory-layout), for details.

**My question**: is there a Bazel option to avoid all these links to be generated or at least an option to tell Bazel to put all these links in another place (in `/tmp/my-project` for instance)?

(My motivation is that I also use other tools that scan *.hpp and *.cpp files in my project directory, unfortunatly all the symlinks generated by Bazel are messing up the result...).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`--symlink_prefix=/` will stop these symlinks from being created.

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html

Comment: I have not tried this yet. Does this trigger the deployment of binaries instead of symlinks? Or am I after a different command-line argument?

Answer (score 11):

Quoting the documentation of [--symlink_prefix](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--symlink_prefix):

> Warning: the special functionality for `/` will be deprecated soon;
>   use `--experimental_convenience_symlinks=ignore` instead.