# Avoid “convenience symlinks” AND output directly to workspace

Tags: build, bazel

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018499/bazel-i-want-to-avoid-all-the-convenience-symlinks-to-be-generated), but one step further - I want to have Bazel skip the symlinking (at least for `BINDIR`) AND output directly to workspace, so that e.g. I see the binary itself under `WORKSPACE\bazel-bin`, not a symlink to that binary elsewhere.

Reason behind doing so is I'm bind mounting the workspace from the host into a Docker container, so that both host/container will have immediate access to both code/output. It doesn't make sense for the host to follow a symlink into the container's filesystem, especially when said container is offline, etc.

Can this even be done? Note that I'm on Bazel 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Bazel is quite insistent on writing to its output tree and not mutating the source tree. You could bind mount the output tree—`bazel info output_base`—into the container, so the symlinks continue to work, though.